# include/require php file within phtml template file

Tags: php-5.4

In one of my magento template phtml files I am trying to include a seperate php file.
When I include it I get nothing outputted and when i use require instead I get the following error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'http://www.site.co.uk/dir/test.php'
(include_path='/home/usr/public_html/app/code/local:/home/usr/public_html/app/code/community:/home/usr/public_html/app/code/core:/home/usr/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/usr/public_html/app/design/frontend/theme/edits/template/review/product/view/list.phtml on line 30
```

The first line of the error shows the correct url path and when i go to it directly it works - it just doesn't like being included/required from the phtml template page.

I've tried the following in the phtml file (using magento's BaseURL, absolute path and the relative path):

```
<?php 
$root = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
require/include ($root.'dir/test.php');
?>

<?php 
require/include ('http://www.site.co.uk/dir/test.php');
?>

<?php 
require/include ('../../../../../../../../../dir/test.php');
?>
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind including the file in this manor and not working it into a block? What does the file do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get installed directory by this code

> Mage::getBaseDir()

So try like this

```
<?php require(Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'dir'.DS.'test.php');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code.

```
<?php 
$root = getcwd();
require/include ($root.'dir/test.php');
?>
```

Now Test it will 100% work. When you call the file from url it will not included you have to include file use Base Directory Path so we have to use `getcwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

Should try `Mage::getBaseDir('base')` which will give magento dir

Also
DS used Directory spectator

```
<?php require_once Mage::getBaseDir('base').DS.'dir'.DS.'test.php';?>
```

More details on http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories