# Get function/value from php file in .phtml

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

[include/require php file within phtml template file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24427/include-require-php-file-within-phtml-template-file)

I have a .phtml file but need to get the return value from another php file by calling it from said .phtml file. How can this be achieved in Magento 2?

I tried using `require`, `include` and `require_once` with the path relative to the location of the .phtml file but this doesn't work (returns 500 error on page).

To make things somewhat clearer (I'm using a custom module):

- I have a Settings.php file in a folder called Helper (folder located in root of custom module, so Vendor/Module/Helper)
- Following, I have a template.phtml file under view/frontend/templates
- I want to get the return value from a function in Settings.php

Comment: I have a .phtml file but need to get the return value from another php means ? Could you please share your some code hunt?

Comment: @KeyurShah see my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call helper in `.phtml` like,

`$helper = $this->helper('YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Helper\Settings');`

Now If you have some function in `Settings.php` then you can call like,

`$helper->getSomethingFromSetting();`

Comment: Same help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/297791/57334  Thanks @Keyur Shah