# Magento 1.9 - How to include custom PHP Script into .PHTML file

Tags: php, error, script, magento1.9.2.3

My magento tracking page:

[image]

Back-end magento code :

[image]

How can i add my PHP script into this tracking page.

Tracking page code  - trackorder.phtml [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySgMA.png]

```
<?php
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('trackorder/trackorder_general/enabled')):
    ?>
    <div class="page-title"><h1><?php echo $this->__('Track Your Order ') ?></h1></div>
    <div  class="form-list">
        <form name="track_order" id="track_order" action="" method="post" onsubmit="sendAjax('track_order','<?php  echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/track');?>'); return false;">
        <!--<form name="track_order" method="post" id="track_order" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/view');?>">-->
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="order_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Order Id') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="order_id" id="order_id" value="" title="" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box" >
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>    
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons-set">
               <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?>" name="track" id="track">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>
        <div id="loading-details" class="loading-details" style="display:none">
            <div id="loading-mask" >
                <p class="loader" id="loading_mask_loader"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('trackorder/images/ajax-loader-tr.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Loading...') ?>"/><br/><?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div id="oderinfo" class="order-info-message"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var validateForm = new VarienForm('track_order', true);
    </script>           
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendAjax(frmId,url){
            if (!validateForm.validator.validate()) {
                return;
            }
            var data = $(frmId).serialize(this);
            $("loading-details").show();


        new Ajax.Updater(
                {
                    success:"oderinfo"
                },

                url,
                {
                    asynchronous:true,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json){
                        $("loading-details").hide();
                        return false;
                    }, 
                    onLoading:function(request, json){},
                    parameters:data
                }
            ); 
            return false;
        }

    </script>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl();
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

From above code how can i add my own PHP script :

My PHP script :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

    <form action="#" method="POST">
        Select Courier :
        <select name="courier">
            <option disabled='disabled' selected>-- Choose an option --</option>
            <option value="professional_courier">Professional Courier</option>
            <option value="shree_maruti_courier">Shree Maruti Courier</option>
            <option value="india_post_courier">India Post Courier</option>
            <option value="dhl_courier">DHL Courier</option>
            <option value="fedex_courier">Fedex Courier</option>
            <option value="ups_courier">UPS Courier</option>
        </select>

        Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['courier'])) {
        // Professional Courier
        if ('professional_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&type=0&service=0");
        }
        // Shree Maruti Courier
        else if ('shree_maruti_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.shreemaruticourier.com/track-your-shipment/#track-your", "_blank");
        }

        // india_post_courier
        else if ('india_post_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.indiapost.gov.in/vas/Pages/IndiaPostHome.aspx/#main-content", "_blank");
        }

        // DHL Courier
        else if ('dhl_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html?AWB=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&brand=DHL", "_blank");
        }

        // Fedex Courier
        else if ('fedex_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&cntry_code=in&locale=en_IN", "_blank");
        }

        // ups_courier
        else if ('ups_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&requester=WT/trackdetails", "_blank");
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

My Workout in trackorder.phtml getting error  : [start & end header added]

```
<?php
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('trackorder/trackorder_general/enabled')):
    ?>
    <div class="page-title"><h1><?php echo $this->__('Track Your Order ') ?></h1></div>
    <div  class="form-list" style="float: left;">
        <form name="track_order" id="track_order" action="" method="post" onsubmit="sendAjax('track_order','<?php  echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/track');?>'); return false;">
        <!--<form name="track_order" method="post" id="track_order" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/view');?>">-->
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="order_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Order Id') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="order_id" id="order_id" value="" title="" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box" >
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>    
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons-set">
               <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?>" name="track" id="track">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>
        <div id="loading-details" class="loading-details" style="display:none">
            <div id="loading-mask" >
                <p class="loader" id="loading_mask_loader"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('trackorder/images/ajax-loader-tr.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Loading...') ?>"/><br/><?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <!-- Start couier tracking -->

      <div style="float: left;">
        <form action="#" method="POST" style="padding: 28px 15px 21px 196px;">
            Select Courier :
            <select name="courier">
            <option disabled='disabled' selected>-- Choose an option --</option>
            <option value="professional_courier">Professional Courier</option>
            <option value="shree_maruti_courier">Shree Maruti Courier</option>
            <option value="india_post_courier">India Post Courier</option>
            <option value="dhl_courier">DHL Courier</option>
            <option value="fedex_courier">Fedex Courier</option>
            <option value="ups_courier">UPS Courier</option>
        </select>

        Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['courier'])) {
        // Professional Courier
        if ('professional_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&type=0&service=0");
        }
        // Shree Maruti Courier
        else if ('shree_maruti_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.shreemaruticourier.com/track-your-shipment/#track-your", "_blank");
        }

        // india_post_courier
        else if ('india_post_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.indiapost.gov.in/vas/Pages/IndiaPostHome.aspx/#main-content", "_blank");
        }

        // DHL Courier
        else if ('dhl_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html?AWB=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&brand=DHL", "_blank");
        }

        // Fedex Courier
        else if ('fedex_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&cntry_code=in&locale=en_IN", "_blank");
        }

        // ups_courier
        else if ('ups_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&requester=WT/trackdetails", "_blank");
        }
    }
    ?>

    </div>

    <!-- End couier tracking -->

    <div id="oderinfo" class="order-info-message"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var validateForm = new VarienForm('track_order', true);
    </script>           
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendAjax(frmId,url){
            if (!validateForm.validator.validate()) {
                return;
            }
            var data = $(frmId).serialize(this);
            $("loading-details").show();


        new Ajax.Updater(
                {
                    success:"oderinfo"
                },

                url,
                {
                    asynchronous:true,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json){
                        $("loading-details").hide();
                        return false;
                    }, 
                    onLoading:function(request, json){},
                    parameters:data
                }
            ); 
            return false;
        }

    </script>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl();
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please more explain with error and log file .

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101914/discussion-between-vishal-baraiya-and-zus

Comment: @zus, are you using any third party module for track order ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes, i am using third party module

Comment: OK, and you want to add a select box after `order Id ` and `email` ?

Comment: Explain what you want, first step to get tracking id and after that redirect to shipping tracking page according to selection. is this right?

Comment: Let me explain from scratch, this is my PHP script https://codeshare.io/5RXrrB and output : https://snipboard.io/4vIKAk.jpg [FYI select drop down choose professional courier and enter : Maa263235424] this will redirect courier website tracking page. I hope you understand what i told. my another point, i want to add this PHP script to https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySgMA.png trackorder.phtml

Comment: My trackorder.phtml -> frontendpage -> https://imgur.com/Z7AuYWr then i just added My php script to trackorder.phtml output -> https://imgur.com/GF397kw, in my tracking page same i chooses professional courier enter tracking number after click submit the link retain same page, the link not redirect to courier website tracking page.

Comment: I hope my point clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

```
     <div style="float: right;">
       <!-- <form method="post" action="" > -->
                Select Courier :
                <li>
                <select name="courier" id="courier" >
                    <option disabled='disabled' selected>-- Choose an option --</option>
                    <option value="professional_courier">Professional Courier</option>
                    <option value="shree_maruti_courier">Shree Maruti Courier</option>
                    <option value="india_post_courier">India Post Courier</option>
                    <option value="dhl_courier">DHL Courier</option>
                    <option value="fedex_courier">Fedex Courier</option>
                    <option value="ups_courier">UPS Courier</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid" id="trackingid">
            </li>
            <li>
                <button id="buttonpost" >submit</button>
            </li>    
   <!-- </form> -->
    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#buttonpost").on("click", function(){      
                var name = jQuery("#courier").val();
                var trackingid=jQuery("#trackingid").val();
                // alert(name);
                if ('professional_courier' == name) {
                     window.location.href="https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id="+ trackingid+"&type=0&service=0";
                }
```