# Magento 1.9 - CMS page products list error

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages, best-seller

Display Bestsellers for Specific Magento Categories in CMS page.

Following tutorial,

https://mercytapscott.com/display-bestsellers-for-specific-magento-categories/

Added following line into cms content

> {{block type="catalog/product_bestseller"
>   template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml" category_id="5"}}

Getting error.

My code :

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php
app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml

If any configuration error or anything else?

error message :

Fatal error: Call to a member function productAttribute() on null in /home/abc/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml on line 6

Comment: please add code of block class and phtml

Comment: @vishal's answer is correct

Comment: @Pawan may i know why we need to declare $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');?

Comment: because in your code you used `<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>` but no where define `$_helper`!

Comment: you first need to create object by `$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');` before using it

Comment: Can i get help for my another one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/297791/57334

Comment: How to display my <ul class="top-products"> list values into bootstrap responsive desigh, now display like one by one, i need like 5 row's, 4 columns and also responsive. How to add bootstrap design for <ul class="top-products">? @Pawan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open below file and declare of helper after flush and check it.

> app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
```

Comment: Where i can declare $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); in my code : https://paste.ofcode.org/UWGbrJwSLyWkehW7yQu5rn

Comment: first line like <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); ?>

Comment: can you check category_id 5 exits and assign product that category?

Comment: Yes, available..

Comment: ok working my code or not ?

Comment: Yes, working.. may i know why we need to declare $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');?

Comment: may i know why we need to declare $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');?

Comment: because you can call of productAttribute function before you need to declare where it is function.

Comment: Can i get help for my another one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/297791/57334

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101914/discussion-between-vishal-baraiya-and-zus).

Comment: How to display my <ul class="top-products"> list values into bootstrap responsive desigh, now display like one by one, i need like 5 row's, 4 columns and also responsive. How to add bootstrap design for <ul class="top-products">? @Vishal Baraiya